# magento can't upload large csv file

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, varien-file-uploader

this is my file upload code when i try to upload file which has size more than 75mb i can't upload file i did't get any error i also change php.ini file still its not working

```
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('csvupload');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('csv'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'uploads';
                    $fname="customer.csv";
                    $uploader->save($path, $fname );
                    $filename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
```

can anybody give solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not Magento but PHP/server settings that are the issue. By default PHP has a much smaller max file and post size.

Check out [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/) on uploading large files. Via your `htaccess` you can change these values. Also make sure the `execution_time` is high enough to process the file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 80M
php_value post_max_size 80M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Comment: i tried your answer but can't solve it...another solution?

Comment: It might be limited by your `php.ini`, or the hosting provider. I would advice contacting them directly to ask if increasing the size is possible

Comment: i also edit php.ini file still its not work and i am working on localhost

Comment: did you restart the server locally? (obvious question but still)

Comment: i just forgot to do this now its working...thank you...

Answer (score 2):

1. Create phpinfo.php file in root. add following code. and run it from browser.

Please check value of **upload_max_file_size**.

2. Remove comment of `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` from index.php. Now test your code. It will show error.
3. Enable log from admin panel and check log file.