# How do I Sell my downloadable file on Magento through URL link

Tags: product, url, downloadable

I am failing to upload my downloadable file through the usual upload file. I am now deciding to upload my downloadable product to the directory of my site and then type their URL in the spaces provided for the "URL". Is that enough if I want to sell my product using the links? If not so what should I do?

Comment: Thanks very much but my original problem is...my site just cannot load downloadable product. It loads up to 100% and finally say "Upload HTTP error" and fails. My host checked the .haccesss for me and all the Apache details there was no problem or hidden passwords. I even adjusted the "Secure" "insecure" settings in Magento...I still got the error so I have given up trying to upload filels in the conventional way I wished if anyone could help but even my Host who happens to be Hostgator failed to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks very much but my original problem is...my site just cannot load downloadable product. It loads up to 100% and finally say "Upload HTTP error" and fails. My host checked the .haccesss for me and all the Apache details there was no problem or hidden passwords.I upgraded the flash of my browser. I even adjusted the "Secure" "insecure" settings in Magento...I still got the error so I have given up trying to upload files in the conventional way I wished if anyone could help but even my Host who happens to be Hostgator failed to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Augustine and welcome to MageOverflow.

I recommend to fix your installation instead of thinking about work arounds.

Open another question, describing what you are doing, what you expect and what doesn't work as expected.

If your files are bigger than 1 or 2MB, checkout https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79015/217 - maybe your settings need to be adjusted.